# User permission to specific Extension in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I have a specific Extension installed in my Joomla version 1.7.2 . I want a particular group of user can access that extension in Joomla Admin how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions for individual modules, plug-ins, extensions, etc for individual user.
Check this link: [Joomla 1.7 ACL](http://www.joomlashine.com/blog/joomla-17-access-control-list-explained.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: I want any SPECIFIC EXTENSION/PLUGIN acccessibilty to be allowed or disallowed to any particular user.. user answer resembles to a global level only not to individual plugin level